# Unable to launch apache twill within hortonworks sandbox and eclipse

Tags: apache, guava, hadoop-yarn, apache-twill

I can not get my development environment up and running a simple twill application within the hortonworks sandbox and eclipse.

I can get everything to compile but I end up running into this error when I launch it within eclipse.

```
17:45:01.367 [IPC Client (23740594) connection to sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8025 from developer] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (23740594) connection to sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8025 from developer: starting, having connections 1
17:45:01.384 [IPC Parameter Sending Thread #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (23740594) connection to sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8025 from developer sending #0
17:45:01.414 [IPC Client (23740594) connection to sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8025 from developer] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (23740594) connection to sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.2.15:8025 from developer got value #0
17:45:01.448 [main] ERROR o.a.twill.yarn.YarnTwillPreparer - Failed to submit application ApiRunnable
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcNoSuchProtocolException: Unknown protocol: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.getProtocolImpl(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is caused by incompatible Hadoop version. You can check the Hadoop version in the sandbox vs the version used in Eclipse.